# Share file between users in iOS / Mac

Tags: ios, cocoa, cloud, icloud

What options do we have to enable a user of an app to share a file with another user on another device ?

My application is a task management app, I want to enable my users to share lists, notes, etc. 
I haven't found a way to do this with iCloud.

Comment: What is the workflow you'd like your users to go through, in order to share?

Comment: I've seen other apps that require a login to their own cloud systems. I don't know if they are developing their own, or if they are renting the service.. However, at this point the app is at planning stage, and opened to any idea.

Comment: This question seems to me a little too broad for this site. Can you work out whether you want the sharing to happen between devices on a LAN or through a server API?

Comment: Parse is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to implement the work-flow, there are a number of ways to accomplish this.

Spotify allows users to sync files between computers and mobile devices, if both are on the same local network. You could use Bonjour to discover if there are any valid endpoints on the local network, and then sync directly over a TCP/IP socket.

If you're looking for cloud sync, [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) provides a cloud-app-api service that lets you easily store objects, including files and binary data on the cloud. You'll have to write your own user management layer, but they provide API's for storing and retrieving data.

From the comments, there are other companies that provide similar services to parse: Buddy, Stackmob, Kinvey, and applicasa to name a few. The idea is to leverage an API-as-a-Service provider for all backend needs.

Comment: Just for completeness if anyone else needs this info. There are other sites growing with this service beside Parse. www.stackmob.com www.kinvey.com & www.applicasa.com

Comment: Ah yes, there are plenty of companies that provide app services, including Buddy.